# OpenERP Property Leasing Management

Tags: openerp-7

I want to install Property leasing management into my OpenERP. I Have found documentation on websites about this module.
http://www.slideshare.net/pragmatic123/open-erp-7-property-leasing-management-7

Can any one let me know where to download it or whether it is a paid or a free module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module is developed by Pragmatic Techsoft Pvt Ltd and you can find the product page here:
http://pragtech.co.in/labs/verticals/openerp-property-rental.html

Most likely you'll have to pay for it. One way to find out is to contact Pragmatic and ask.

Comment: Hi thanks. I already called them we need to pay for that module.